# Mi sitio web muestra error crítico en la web

Tags: wordpress, web

Estuve actualizando pluggings en mi e-commerce, una vez realicé estas actualizaciones, intenté ingresar pero me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: error critico en la web]

Comment: Cuál es el error crítico?

Comment: es probablemente la version de php, el primer warning es debido a que la extension php para mysql/mariadb no se corresponde con la version de php o mysql (  php-mysql es un meta package tal vez necesites php7.4-mysql o php8.2-mysql segun la versión de php). los deprecated return type pueden ser codigo php5 en php 7 o codigo php 7 en php 8.1/php 8.2. La sugerencia de [`#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]`](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/ReturnTypeWillChange) indicaría que has upgradeado a php 8.x y el código del plugin no es del too compatible